# Bash command inPython not outputting anything to terminal

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to run a bash command to launch Nikto and display the output in the terminal, howevever nothing is getting returned from the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

The command runs fine in the terminal before input to the python program

```
import subprocess
import os

def bash(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', command])

def niktoScan():
    res = bash('nikto -Display 1234EP -o report.html -Format htm -Tuning 123bde -host 127.0.0.1').splitlines()
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you've only defined the functions but haven't called them. If I understand correctly, you can just add `niktoScan()` to the end:

```py
import subprocess
import os

def bash(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', command])

def niktoScan():
    res = bash('nikto -Display 1234EP -o report.html -Format htm -Tuning 123bde -host 127.0.0.1').splitlines()
    print(res)

niktoScan()
```

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to add that to the end of my code. The program still just waits and does'nt return any output